# Batch "file not found"

Tags: batch-file, file-not-found

I am making a secure folder application in batch and have run into an error.

The lock command:

```
:lock
ren "Secure Folder" "Secure Folder (Locked)"
attrib +h +s "Secure Folder (Locked)"
msg * Folder locked.
goto end
```

The unlock command (Where the error is):

```
:unlock
attrib -h -s "Secure Folder (Locked)"
ren "Secure Folder (Locked)" "Secure Folder"
pause
::Pause is to see the error
goto end
```

The error is:

```
File not found - Secure Folder (Locked)
```

This is how the folder is created:

```
:creation
md "Secure Folder"
cd Secure Folder
md Movies
md Pictures
md Music
md Bonuses
cd Bonuses
echo .LOG>Log.txt
cd %USERPROFILE%
md userpass
cd userpass
set /p userpass=Enter the password you would like to use for this application: 
echo %userpass%>userpass.txt
msg * Folder created.
goto end
```

And this is how the unlock is initialized:

```
:password
cd %USERPROFILE%\userpass
<userpass.txt set /p userpass=
set /p password=Enter password to unlock:
If /I "%password%"=="%userpass%" goto unlock
goto fail
```

I have a program used to unlock the folder when I get errors. The code of that program is:

```
@echo off
attrib -h -s "Secure Folder (Locked)"
ren "Secure Folder (Locked)" "Secure Folder"
```

I have no idea why my main code does not work. Could it be because of using "cd %USERPROFILE%" earlier?

I have tried to move the "unlock" code to the top of my code.

Comment: _"Could it be because of using "cd" .."_ Where is that code? You're showing some parts of the code.

Comment: Added all important code (i think)

Comment: My guess is that the `cd` was done to a directory with no folder named "Secure Folder".  How about throwing in a `dir` command before the `pause`, and see what's really there?

Comment: There are some quotation marks missing in cd Secure Folder.

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm, the `CD` command is one of the few commands that does not need quotes to protect spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `cd` to child folders, but never return to where the parent lives. You could have done `pushd` and `popd` instead, but this is a better method:

```
:creation
(md "Secure Folder\Movies"
md "Secure Folder\Pictures"
md "Secure Folder\Music"
md "Secure Folder\Bonuses
echo .LOG>"Secure Folder\Bonuses\Log.txt"
md "%USERPROFILE%\userpass"
)>nul 2>&1
set /p userpass=Enter the password you would like to use for this application: 
(echo %userpass%)>"%USERPROFILE%\userpass\userpass.txt"
msg * Folder created.
goto :eof
```

You can create folders without having to cd to each. In other words:

```
mkdir "folder1\folder2\folder3"
```

Will create the entire tree, you do not have to create the parent, then the  children.

a Slightly shorter version, by using a for loop to create the folders:

```
:creation
(for %%i in ("Movies" "Pictures" "Music" "Bonuses") do md "Secure Folder\%%~i"
echo .LOG>"Secure Folder\Bonuses\Log.txt"
md "%USERPROFILE%\userpass"
)>nul 2>&1
set /p "userpass=Enter the password you would like to use for this application: "
(echo %userpass%)>"%USERPROFILE%\userpass\userpass.txt"
msg * Folder created.
goto :eof
```

The method above makes sure you keep inside of the original working `dir`.

Note, you should amend the remaining code to adapt this method.

```
:password
<"%USERPROFILE%\userpass\userpass.txt" set /p userpass=
set /p password=Enter password to unlock:
If /I "%password%" == "%userpass%" goto unlock
goto fail
```

Comment: Also consider removing `/i` from the password `if` statement, it kind off defeats password complexity adding caps if you'll match any case, not as if this is secure at all, I will crack your secure folder in 5 seconds flat, just giving you some hints `:)`

Comment: Thanks! I tried it just now and it worked perfectly!